# Are Wysiwyg and CKEditor modules incompatible now?

Tags: wysiwyg

Apologies if this question has been raised elsewhere, but I couldn't find anything directly related to it.

I'm in the process of setting up my first Drupal site. I want to be able to include images in the body of posts but without turning on "full HTML". Chapter 4 of *Using Drupal* (2nd Edition) describes a way of doing that involves using both the Wysiwyg and CKEditor modules.

However, when I install the latest versions of both modules (Wysiwyg: 7.x-2.2; CKEditor: 7.x-1.13), I get the following message on the CKEditor configuration page:

> "The WYSIWYG module was detected. Using both modules at the same time may cause problems. It is recommended to turn the WYSIWYG module off (click here to disable)."

If I ignore the message and try to configure Wysiwyg I get the following message:

> "The version of CKEditor could not be detected.
>   Extract the archive and copy its contents into a new folder in the following location:
>   sites/all/libraries/ckeditor
>
> So the actual library can be found at:
>   sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"

But ckeditor.js is saved in the above directory.

I've tried installing other editors besides CKEditor (e.g., TinyMCE), but I get a similar result.

I've got CKEditor installed and working fine, but it only generates HTML code, not tags that the Media module can process. Consequently, images only appear in "Full HTML" mode, not in "filtered HTML" mode.

I'm really interested in finding out how can I include images in posts using filtered HTML mode (either by using CKEditor/Wysiwyg or by some other method). Very grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you use one or the other of the [CKEditor](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor) & [WYSIWYG](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) modules.

They both provide the same sort of functionality.

As to which is better is up to your preference. You can try them both and see which one you prefer.